# split string based on special characters python

Tags: python, string

I have a string as such:

```
teststring = 'Index: WriteVTKOutput.FOR\\r\\n======================================\\r\\n'
```

I'd like to split it based on the `'\\r'` and `'\\n'` characters, such that I get the following result:

```
testlist = ['Index: WriteVTKOutput.FOR', '======================================']
```

I tried the following commands, none of which worked:

```
teststring.split(r'\r\n')
teststring.splitlines()
```

How does a man split that string into those delimiters while retaining his dignity and keeping it real?

Thanks

Comment: none worked? how? I get your output with an extra empty string.

Comment: how do I get rid of that extra empty string?

Comment: `teststring.strip(r'\r\n')` before you `split()`

Comment: @SeanBreckenridge No no no no no. That'll strip any "r" and "n" characters from the ends of the string. `'rain'.strip(r'\r\n')` -> `'ai'`

Comment: @Aran-Fey true (even if I'm not sure that it's really important since those chars seem to come in pairs). But the issue is the performance: creating 1 stripped string to be able to split it properly (when the string is big) isn't very efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
lst = teststring.split("\\r\\n")[:-1]
```

Comment: it will still give empty element at the end

Answer (score 1):

`splitlines` won't work because your separators aren't really line separators. They're just the actual `\r\n` chars.

You can get rid of trailing/leading empty fields that `split` generates by an extra comprehension in case your string starts or ends by `r"\r\n"`:

```
[x for x in teststring.split(r'\r\n') if x]
```

result:

```
['Index: WriteVTKOutput.FOR', '======================================']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
teststring = 'Index: WriteVTKOutput.FOR\\r\\n======================================\\r\\n'
print(teststring.split("\\r\\n")[:-1])
print(teststring.strip("\\r\\n").split("\\r\\n"))
```

Output

```
['Index: WriteVTKOutput.FOR', '======================================']
['Index: WriteVTKOutput.FOR', '======================================']
```

Answer (score 0):

You need : `'\\r\\n'` or r'\r\n'

```
teststring = 'Index: WriteVTKOutput.FOR\\r\\n======================================\\r\\n'
new_string = [x for x in teststring.split('\\r\\n') if x]
```